# How to remove ContentEdit.Static element in ContentTools

Tags: wysiwyg

I created a new tool in ContentTools that adds a static table (I don't want you to edit).

But being a static element doesn't maintain focus and I can not remove it when I click remove button.

I can do so that the table is not editable but can be removed if you click on it?

That's how I created the element:

```
new ContentEdit.Static('div', {'data-ce-moveable': true}, '<table><thead><tr><th>Foo head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Foo body</td></tr></tbody></table>')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static elements can't be interacted with for the most part (other elements can be dragged around them but that's about it). ContentEdit/Tools does allow you to restrict the some behaviour for elements but not being able to modify the content of a text element isn't one right now (though I think this might be a worthy addition).

However whilst there's no set way to do this at the moment here's an approach you can use that should provide the behaviour you describe (do let me know how you get on):

```
ContentEdit.Root.get().bind('mount', function(element) {
    // We only care about `TableCell` elements
    if (element.type() != 'TableCell') {
        return;
    }

    // We only want to make the element read-only if the parent table has
    // the `data-read-only` attribute.
    var table = element.closest(function(node) {
        return node.type() == 'Table';
    });

    if (table.attr('data-read-only') !== undefined) {
        // Disable text editing for the table cell
        element.tableCellText()._onKeyDown = function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    // Disable dragging of the table rows
    var tableRow = element.closest(function(node) {
        return node.type() == 'TableRow';
    });

    tableRow.can('drag', false);
    tableRow.can('drop', false);
});
```

Comment: It seems to work. When I have more knowledge about the inner workings of the library I would like to contribute by adding features like this. Thank you